# Page not working conditionally in angular

Tags: angular

I have an angular app and here is the setup:

1) PageStateService:

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PageStateService {
  page: string = "board";

  changePage(switchTo: string) {
    console.log("X");
    this.page = switchTo;
    console.log(this.page);
  }

  constructor() {}
}
```

2) Every Component has this service included and injected as a dependency.

3) Dashboard Component:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
    <div class="sub-wrapper">
        <app-bar></app-bar>
        <app-board ng-if="pageState.page === 'board'"></app-board>
        <app-stock ng-if="pageState.page === 'stock'"></app-stock>
    </div>
</div>
```

4) I have a sidenav component that is responsible for changing the state:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light active" (click)="pageState.changePage('board')">
  <span>
    <i class="material-icons">
      dashboard
    </i>
  </span> Dashboard</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" (click)="pageState.changePage('stock')">
  <span>
    <i class="material-icons">
      store
    </i>
  </span> Stock</button>
```

**The Problem:** When I click a button, the console logs the page variable along with X as seen in the service but the ng-if doesn't work. It doesn't check for the page variable and render the component. I also tried ng-show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-if` is AngularJS syntax, try `*ngIf="pageState.page === 'board'"`

Make sure you define injected service as `public` so that it is accessible from HTML template.

Comment: Can't bind to 'ng-if' since it isn't a known property of 'app-board'.
1. If 'app-board' is an Angular component and it has 'ng-if' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-board' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
    <div class="sub-wrapper">
        <app-bar></app-bar>
        <app-board [ERROR ->]*ng-if="pageState.page === 'board'"></app-board>

Comment: this happened after adding the asterisk.

Comment: You don't just add asterisk, it is `*ngIf` not `*ng-if`

Comment: You are a legend. I need to work on my syntax...the help on internet is all mixed up. All due to the versioning in angular. Thanks...Ill accept answer in 7 minutes since I am not allowed to accept it now...what happens when the injected service is private? Cuz, in tutorials, I have seen they say you can use any

Comment: Thanks in advance for accepting, glad I could help.

If you define the service as private it will not be "seen" by HTML template, compiler will fail when you do `ng build --prod`.

Comment: `the help on internet is all mixed up. All due to the versioning in angular` : use the only source of truth : https://angular.io/docs. No AngularJS, only Angular.